# MPAndroidChart, How to change the position of my draw value in my Scatter chart?

Tags: java, android, charts, mpandroidchart

I use MPAndroidChart to display a Scatter chart. Each of my value is display correctly but I wish to change the position of the draw value of each dot in the chart. Indeed, the draw value position is to high and I wish to put it closer to my dot.

```
List<Entry> myValueEntries = generateEntries();
ScatterDataSet myValueDataset = new ScatterDataSet(myValueEntries, "my Value");
myValueDataset.setFormSize(18f);
myValueDataset.setDrawValues(true);
ScatterData strikeCatchScatterData = new ScatterData(myValueDataset);

binding.myChart.setData(strikeCatchScatterData); // ScatterChart in the view
binding.myChart.getXAxis().setDrawAxisLine(false);
binding.myChart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);
binding.myChart.getXAxis().setGranularity(1f);
binding.myChart.getXAxis().setAxisMinimum(-1f);
binding.myChart.getXAxis().setDrawLabels(true);
binding.myChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
binding.myChart.getAxisRight().setDrawGridLines(false);
binding.myChart.getAxisLeft().setDrawGridLines(false);
binding.myChart.getAxisLeft().setDrawLabels(false);

binding.fishingSessionDetailActivityChart.invalidate();
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, I just wanted to have the drawValue closer to the form. Unfortunately I am unable to achieve this using a scatter chart, so in the wait of a answer, I use a Linechart where I display the drawnValue (which is strangely closer to the form)   and remove the line using :

```
myLineDataset.setcolor(Color.alpha(0));
```

Doing so, the legend will also be invisible. I display then using a Imageview and Textview

Hope to have a better solution